# UWP Application Third party SDK

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, desktop-bridge

I have a WPF application that is using a third party SDK to control a camera ( through its specific driver ).
I'm wondering if such an application can be converted to a UWP Application.
Indeed, I don't have the source code of this SDK, it's accessing some XML settings file on disk and it's dealing with the driver to communicate with the camera.

What is the best way to convert to UWP ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If your application meets all the points listed here, you will be able to use the Desktop Bridge to convert your app to a Universal Windows App package:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare

The steps to do the conversion are documented here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter

Note that when testing the converted app you may potentially find bugs that need to be addressed in the 3rd party library code. For those you would need to reach out to the library vendor. But chances are it will just work.